# Connecting to SQL Server database from a .net application

Tags: sql-server, database-design, logins, connections, data-tier-application

I need to add a new form to an application which requires access to SQL Server to retrieve data from a single view and display it to the user. This application is an enterprise level application with ~1000 users.

I assume the best practice is to ask DBA to provide a system account with non-expiring password so I can use it to connect to the SQL Server.

Is there any other alternative to using SQL Database account?

How should I write the connection string in my code?

Comment: windows or sql authentication?

Comment: In order to use Windows Authentication all users need to have access to the DB, which I don't think it's the best practice

Comment: That depends. If all users' access to the database is appropriately controlled (for example, if they can't manage to run ad hoc SQL that drops tables), then most organizations would *prefer* to provide access that can be tracked back to a specific individual. If your view is in its own schema, and users aren't granted access to the schema with the actual tables, I would think it would be workable. Of course, flip side, a SQL login that can't make any changes would be equally secure (unless access to the data itself should be highly restricted).

Comment: See [Using Entity Framework With an Existing Database: Data Access](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/net-framework/using-entity-framework-with-an-existing-database-data-access/) by Jon Smith.

Comment: "I need to add..." To an existing application? How does the application handle security now? I would recommend that you follow the conventions already in place.

Comment: Most modern applications handle security at application level using domain credentials, but behind the scenes they connect to the database with a single service acct.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to connect to Database.

**1. ADO.NET**

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;

class Sample
{
  public static void Main() 
  {
    OleDbConnection nwindConn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=northwind");

    OleDbCommand catCMD = nwindConn.CreateCommand();
    catCMD.CommandText = "SELECT CategoryID, CategoryName FROM Categories";

    nwindConn.Open();

    OleDbDataReader myReader = catCMD.ExecuteReader();

    while (myReader.Read())
    {
      Console.WriteLine("\t{0}\t{1}", myReader.GetInt32(0), myReader.GetString(1));
    }

    myReader.Close();
    nwindConn.Close();
  }
}
```

**2. Web.Config Connection String**

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnStringDb1" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=YourDataBaseName;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

**3. Connect to a SQL Database and Use the LINQ to SQL Designer**

This process involves multiple thing, you can read more here

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/charlie/2007/11/19/connect-to-a-sql-database-and-use-the-linq-to-sql-designer/